# download HTTP/HTTPS URIs with DownloadManager

Tags: android, https

I googled and find something about this. But that doesn't help.

Android Version: 4.0+
here's my code:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
```

And my url is https://static.test.com/downloads/xxx.apk

Scheme is https, but I still get an error:

```
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.souyidai.investment.android.service.DownloadService@4344e5e0 with Intent { act=download_with_download_manager cmp=com.souyidai.investment.android/.service.DownloadService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs:  https://static.test.com/downloads/xxx.apk
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2711)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1299)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs:  https://static.test.com/downloads/xxx.apk
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.<init>(DownloadManager.java:642)
02-10 11:18:23.710 E/AndroidRuntime( 7550):     at com.souyidai.investment.android.service.DownloadService.onStartCommand(DownloadService.java:114)
```

Here's the DownloadManager.Request code:

```
    public Request(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        if (scheme == null || (!scheme.equals("http") && !scheme.equals("https"))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: " + uri);
        }
        mUri = uri;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had the same problem. For some reason, my url had one kind of white space before the "https". Using `trim()` on the url String solved the problem.

Comment: We have the same problem.

Comment: @EIYeante
Same problem on Galaxy S4, but trim() not fixing the problem... PLease help

Answer (score 1):

Here is What helped me:

Just replace " \" this in your URL with **""**.

Like this:

```
pdfUrl.replace("\", "").trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error was caused by the wrong address. Check your URL.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
addAndroidDownloads: {
          mediaScannable: true, // these two lines resolve the crash on first download
          mime: 'image/*', // define mime type also
```

Comment: Where exactly did you configure this?

Comment: @cmptrwizard inside the package call function configuration in RN application [NOT FOR ANDROID NATIVE]