# Getting "MalformedURLException: no protocol" on a valid URL

Tags: java, android, url, https, malformedurlexception

I'm trying to access and download an image hosted on Google Cloud Storage with a signed URL, but it's throwing a MalformedURLException if I pass the signed URL string along as a parameter.  I know it's a valid URL, as pasting it into my browser works.

This doesn't work:

```java
URL url = new URL(signedUrl);
```

However, pasting the output of `System.out.println(signedUrl)` into the URL object does work.

```java
System.out.println(signedUrl);
URL url = new URL("https://storage.googleapis.com/rydr/insurance_documents/test123.png?X...");
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "https://storage.googleapis.com/rydr/insurance_documents/test123.png?X..."
```

Several years ago, a StackOverflow user had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423700/download-http-https-uris-with-downloadmanager), but the suggestions of using `.trim()` failed to resolve the issue for me.

I also tried using DownloadManager, but it throws a similar exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: "https://storage.googleapis.com/rydr/insurance_documents/test123.png?X..."
```

Comment: Clearly there is an invisible character in `https:`. Check.

Comment: *"I know it's a valid URL, as pasting it into my browser works."* - That's not a definitive test.  A typical browser's URL bar will silently "fix" various problems in the URL to make it valid.  The `URL` class is not as forgiving.  If `URL` says it is invalid, then it >is< invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After viewing the PHP script which generates the signed URL in the browser, I found that it was outputting the URL inside double quotes.

Manually removing the double quotes in Java fixed the problem:

```java
URL url = new URL(signedUrl.replace("\"", ""));
```

Comment: Better still fix the PHP, the source of the problem. Otherwise you are just writing software with a thousand crutches.